# Excel Match Numbers in 2 Columns to a Number in a 3rd

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I've run into a bit of a road block. I get a .PDF output from an accounting program and copy/paste the data into excel, then convert text to columns. I am trying to match the GL code with the totals for that specific account. Columns A, B, and C show the state of my data prior to sorting it, and the lines under Intended Output show how I would like the data to output.

I am trying to automate this process, so I can paste data into columns A, B, & C in the raw format and have it automatically spit out the required numbers in the format of the Intended Output. The GL codes remain the same, but the numbers and the number of rows will change. I've color coded them for ease of review.

Thank you very much in advance!

[image: Image 1]

Comment: What have you tried so far? This should be easy enough to achieve with VBA, looping through the values in the first column.

Comment: Are you sure the value in Data 1 is actually a number and not text?  left justification usually indicates text, and the - in the middle is usually another good indicator of text

Comment: I've tried Pivot Tables, INDEX/MATCH, Advanced Filtering, etc. Someone gave me a VBA code for it and it works, but I have little experience in VBA, so I don't fully understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of the following formulas you can create a list of filtered results.  It works on the principal that you Data1 text that you want to pull is the only text with a "-" in it,  and that the totals you are pulling from Data2 and Data3 are the only numbers in the column.  Any change to that pattern will most likely break the system.  Note the formulas will not copy formatting.

- IFERROR
- INDEX
- AGGREGATE
- ROW
- ISNUMBER
- FIND

Lets assume the output will be place in a small table with E2 being the upper left data location.

In E2 use the following formula and copy down as needed:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$30)/ISNUMBER(FIND("-",$A$1:$A$30)),ROW(A1))),"")
```

In F2 use the following formula and copy to the right 1 column and down as needed:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$30)/ISNUMBER(B$1:B$30),ROW(A1))),"")
```

[image: POC]

AGGREGATE performs array like calculations.  As such, do not use full column references such as A:A in it as it can lead to excess calculations.  Be sure to limit it to the range you are looking at.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate this, unlike VBA, I understand this formula, I just didn't know how to replicate what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this procedure:

 Public Sub bruce_wayne()
 'Assumptions
 '1. Data spreadsheet will ALWAYS have the structure shown in the question
 '2. The key word "Total" (or whatever else it might be) is otherwise NOT found
 '        anywhere else in the 1st data column
 '3. output is written to the same sheet as the data
 '4. As written, invoked when data sheet is the active sheet
 '5. set the 1st 3 constants to the appropriate values

 Const sData2ReadTopLeft = "A1"      'Top left cell of data to process
 Const sData2WriteTopLeft = "J2"     'Top left cell of where to write output
 Const sSearchText = "Total"         'Keyword for summary data

 '*******************
 Const sReplaceText = "Wakanda"

 Dim r2Search As Range
 Dim sAccountCode As String
 Dim rSearchText As Range
 Dim iRowsProcessed As Integer

 Set r2Search = Range(sData2ReadTopLeft).EntireColumn
 sAccountCode = Range(sData2ReadTopLeft).Offset(1, 0).Value
 iRowsProcessed = 0

 Do While Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r2Search, sSearchText) > 0
    Set rSearchText = r2Search.Find(sSearchText)
       Range(sData2WriteTopLeft).Offset(iRowsProcessed, 0) = sAccountCode
       Range(sData2WriteTopLeft).Offset(iRowsProcessed, 1) = rSearchText.Offset(0, 1).Value
       Range(sData2WriteTopLeft).Offset(iRowsProcessed, 2) = rSearchText.Offset(0, 2).Value ' add this if there are more summary columns to return
       'last two lines could be collapsed into a single line; at the expense of readability..

       rSearchText.Value = sReplaceText 'so that next search will find the next instance of the trigger text

       iRowsProcessed = iRowsProcessed + 1

       sAccountCode = rSearchText.Offset(1, 0).Value
 Loop
 r2Search.Replace what:=sReplaceText, Replacement:=sSearchText
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I am not the best with VBA, but I *really* appreciate your comments in the code above because I am trying to get a crash course in understanding it, and you've been very helpful. Thank you again.